# I am getting a "Trying to get property of non-object" error from my controller

Tags: php, laravel

I am getting a "Trying to get property of non-object" error whenever I try to process a deposit in my controller

Here is my controller

```
 users::where('id',$user->id)
  ->update([
  'confirmed_plan' => $deposit->plan,
  'activated_at' => \Carbon\Carbon::now(),
  'last_growth' => \Carbon\Carbon::now(),
  ]);
    //get plan
    $p=plans::where('id',$deposit->plan)->first();
    //get settings 
    $settings=settings::where('id', '=', '1')->first();
    $earnings=$settings->referral_commission*$p->price/100;

  //increment the user's referee total clients activated by 1
  agents::where('agent',$user->ref_by)->increment('total_activated', 1);
  agents::where('agent',$user->ref_by)->increment('earnings', $earnings);
  }

  //update deposits
  deposits::where('id',$id)
  ->update([
  'status' => 'Processed',
  ]);
  return redirect()->back()
  ->with('message', 'Action Sucessful!');
}
```

And The Error seems to be at this line of code

```
    $earnings=$settings->referral_commission*$p->price/100;
```

And Here is my process deposit view blade

```
@include('header')
    <!-- //header-ends -->
    <!-- main content start-->
    <div id="page-wrapper">
        <div class="main-page signup-page">
            <h3 class="title1">Manage clients deposits</h3>

            @if(Session::has('message'))
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissable">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                        <i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> {{ Session::get('message') }}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            @endif

            <div class="bs-example widget-shadow table-responsive" data-example-id="hoverable-table"> 
                <table class="table table-hover"> 
                    <thead> 
                        <tr> 
                            <th>ID</th> 
                            <th>Client name</th>
                            <th>Client email</th>
                            <th>Amount</th>
                            <th>Payment mode</th>
                            <th>Plan</th>
                            <th>Status</th> 
                            <th>Date created</th>
                            <th>Option</th>
                        </tr> 
                    </thead> 
                    <tbody> 
                        @foreach($deposits as $deposit)
                        <tr> 
                            <th scope="row">{{$deposit->id}}</th>
                            <td>{{$deposit->duser->name}}</td>
                            <td>{{$deposit->duser->email}}</td> 
                             <td>${{$deposit->amount}}</td> 
                             <td>{{$deposit->payment_mode}}</td>
                             @if(isset($deposit->dplan->name)) 
                             <td>{{$deposit->dplan->name}}</td>
                             @else
                             <td>For withdrawal</td>
                             @endif
                             <td>{{$deposit->status}}</td> 
                             <td>{{$deposit->created_at}}</td> 
                             <td> <a class="btn btn-default" href="{{ url('dashboard/pdeposit') }}/{{$deposit->id}}">Process</a></td> 
                        </tr> 
                        @endforeach
                    </tbody> 
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @include('modals')
    @include('footer')
```

I keep getting "Trying to get property of non-object" error without any explanation as to where to look at. I need help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you have a `$settings` object with `id` of 1?

```
$settings=settings::where('id', '=', '1')->first();  // <-- why 1, why not just first()?
```

If you are hard coding a single id for a single setting into the DB that will always be the same, and always id of 1... consider just adding that to code instead.

Also check on `$deposit->plan` -- is this correct, or maybe should this be `$deposit->plan_id` or similar?  Perhaps the `$p` is null because there is no value for `$deposit->plan`.

You can set some error checking here by checking for null ahead of the calculation:

```
if(isset($settings) && isset($p)){
    $earnings=$settings->referral_commission*$p->price/100;
} 
else
{
    $earnings = 0; // or whatever you want to replace it with should there be no setting
}
```

Comment: Add a parens at the end - I missed it:  `if(isset($settings) && isset($p)) {`

Comment: Quick note, `settings::first()` won't necessarily return the record with id = 1. In Postgres for example, the results are somewhat random. If you're gonna replace that line, better to use `settings::find(1)`.

Comment: Add a ; at the end of the earnings.  I just wrote this in the text as an example - you should try to make it your own, including checking for syntax.  So: `$earnings = 0;`  I'll edit the answer to correct, but was really meant as an example to help you see a potential path to take.

Comment: Glad to help.  But also check for root cause of the error like is the id 1 actually in the database, or does $deposit->plan have an id, or does it need a different variable etc.  :)